# In tornado, how can I use static_url() in a class without tornado.web.RequestHandler?

Tags: python, tornado, static-linking, requesthandler

I'm using Tornado and I want to load some static files in the template. Now I use `tornado.web.UIModule` to load them. But I got some errors which said `static_url()` is not defined. So I looked up the documentation and found this function is a method of `tornado.web.RequestHandler`. But how can I load the static files like this function in my class below?

```
# _ * _ coding:utf-8 _ * _

import tornado.web
from tornado import template

class Header(tornado.web.UIModule):
"""docstring for Header"""
def render(self, hightlight = "index"):
    return self.render_string("header.html", hightlight = hightlight)

def css_files(self):
    css = [
        static_url("css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css"),
        static_url("css/common.css"),
        static_url("css/jquery.jqplot.min.css"),
        static_url("css/blue/style.css"),
        static_url("css/jquery.vector-map.css")
    ]
    return css;

def javascript_files(self):
    javascript = [
        static_url("js/convert.color.js"),
        static_url("js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"),
        static_url("js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"),
        static_url("js/common.js"),
        static_url("js/jquery.jqplot.min.js"),
        static_url("js/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"),
        static_url("js/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"),
        static_url("js/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"),
        static_url("js/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"),
        static_url("js/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"),
        static_url("js/jquery.vector-map.js"),
        static_url("js/china-cn.js"),
        static_url("js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"),
        static_url("js/charts.js")
    ]
    return javascript

def html_body(self):
    return "<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src=\"{{ static_url(\"js/excanvas.js\") }}\"></script><![endif]-->"

def embedded_javascript(self):
    return "<script>var current = null;</script>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to. If you give a relative path (in `javascript_files` and `css_files`, Tornado will automatically run it through `static_url`.

Comment: got it, thank you. and, what is the most common and recommended way to load template? using `tornado.web.UIModule` or just `block` `extends`?

Comment: UIModules are different than templates. I guess using block and extends is simplest.

Comment: are you sure? because I just checked it and tornado doesn't seem to serve via static_url module. If I am not wrong, if it is passed via static_url module there will be version hash in the url (which can be seen in the source code in browser) something like `/static/js/myjs.js?v=058b0f38e33db6f1001750ba9fd93920`. But tornado doesn't seem to do that. But when I import static module in my UI Modules and use it, I see the version hash.

Comment: In required files for UIModules, it's automatic (again, if it's a relative path). In templates, it is not, and static_url must be called. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, `static_url` is a method of `tornado.web.RequestHandler`, but you're calling it as a global function.

Change

```
static_url(...)
```

to

```
self.handler.static_url(...)
```

Comment: no, i've read the documentation that the `static_url()` is a method of tornado.web.RequestHandler, but here i use the `tornado.web.UIModule` instead of `tornado.web.RequestHandler`. Therefore, your suggestion raised the `AttributeError` because the objects here(Header for instance) has no attribute `static_url`

Comment: thanks, this way works, but as @cole-maclean mentioned, tornado will automatically load these static files through `static_url()`